# Timeout waiting for privilege escalation prompt

Tags: ssh, ansible, centos, sshd

## Context

**I'm asking this question because those two questions/answerse ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598354/ansible-playbook-failed-timeout-12s-waiting-for-privilege-escalation-prompt) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598354/ansible-playbook-failed-timeout-12s-waiting-for-privilege-escalation-prompt)) have little context, and I'd liket o expand on it.**

I'm trying to provision CentOS7 production servers with [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) client 2.8 . My environment consist one master node ([NIS Server](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_25&p=nis&f=1)) and one compute node ([NIS Client](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_25&p=nis&f=2)). Before provisioning live servers, I setted up a virtual lab (vlab) from VirtualBoxes, which mimics production environment. I copied my public keys to both production and vlab environment.

## Problem

My playbooks work with vlab. Unfortunately, the same commands/playbooks are failing against production nodes to which I have ssh password less access and sudo rights. The only feedback that I get is this error `"Timeout (7s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: \u001b[?1h\u001b=\r\r"`

## Question

Does anyone know what causes this behaviour and how to fix it?  I tried SeLinux permissions on home directory, I ended up disabling it (`sudo setenforce 0`). I'm arriving to a conclusion that there has to be something external that stops ansible but?

## Debugging, logging

**Ansible Config**

```
# config file for ansible -- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg

[defaults]
timeout = 5
inventory = ./config/hosts
remote_user = lukas
```

**SSHD Config**

```sh
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes
UseDNS no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

**Ansible log**

```sh
# checking kernel version
$ uname -a
Linux compute01 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64

# pinging compute node
$ ansible -m ping compute01
123.123.123.123 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}

# installing vim
$ ansible compute01 -m yum -a 'name=vim state=installed' -b -K -u lukas
ansible 2.8.4
  config file = /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/lukas/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Using /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/ansible.cfg as config file
BECOME password: 
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/config/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/config/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/config/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Not replacing invalid character(s) "set([u'-'])" in group name (kubernetes-master)
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters in group names by default, this will change, but still be user configurable on deprecation. This feature will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
 deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
....
Parsed /home/lukas/Coding/projects/nebula-provision/ansible/producion/config/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.pyc
META: ran handlers
<123.123.123.123> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: lukas
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 123.123.123.123 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861="` echo /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<123.123.123.123> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861=/home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861\n', 'OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12697\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<123.123.123.123> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<123.123.123.123> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: lukas
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 123.123.123.123 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<123.123.123.123> (0, 'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python2.7\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', 'OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12697\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<123.123.123.123> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: lukas
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 123.123.123.123 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<123.123.123.123> (0, '{"osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"CentOS Linux\\"\\nVERSION=\\"7 (Core)\\"\\nID=\\"centos\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"rhel fedora\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"7\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"CentOS Linux 7 (Core)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:centos:centos:7\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.centos.org/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugs.centos.org/\\"\\n\\nCENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT=\\"CentOS-7\\"\\nCENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION=\\"7\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"centos\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"7\\"\\n\\n", "platform_dist_result": ["centos", "7.3.1611", "Core"]}\n', 'OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12697\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<123.123.123.123> PUT /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12685VGhDEA/tmpwDBaIn TO /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 '[123.123.123.123]'
<123.123.123.123> (0, 'sftp> put /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12685VGhDEA/tmpwDBaIn /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/AnsiballZ_setup.py\n', 'OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12697\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug2: Remote version: 3\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "posix-rename@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "statvfs@openssh.com" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "fstatvfs@openssh.com" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "hardlink@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "fsync@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug3: Sent message fd 5 T:16 I:1\r\ndebug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> /home/lukas size 0\r\ndebug3: Looking up /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12685VGhDEA/tmpwDBaIn\r\ndebug3: Sent message fd 5 T:17 I:2\r\ndebug3: Received stat reply T:101 I:2\r\ndebug1: Couldn\'t stat remote file: No such file or directory\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_OPEN I:3 P:/home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/AnsiballZ_setup.py\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:4 O:0 S:32768\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 4 32768 bytes at 0\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:5 O:32768 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:6 O:65536 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:7 O:98304 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:8 O:131072 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:9 O:163840 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:10 O:196608 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:11 O:229376 S:23124\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 5 32768 bytes at 32768\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 6 32768 bytes at 65536\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 7 32768 bytes at 98304\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 8 32768 bytes at 131072\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 9 32768 bytes at 163840\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 10 32768 bytes at 196608\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 11 23124 bytes at 229376\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_CLOSE I:4\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<123.123.123.123> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: lukas
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 123.123.123.123 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/ /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<123.123.123.123> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12697\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<123.123.123.123> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: lukas
<123.123.123.123> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="lukas"' -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o ControlPath=/home/lukas/.ansible/cp/779c431db0 -tt 123.123.123.123 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=kuswqyltevcovqytnefnxinbrwvcydkq] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-kuswqyltevcovqytnefnxinbrwvcydkq ; /usr/bin/python /home/lukas/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566570853.88-235437120093861/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
123.123.123.123 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Timeout (7s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: \u001b[?1h\u001b=\r\r"
```

**sshd log**

```sh
Aug 26 13:36:19 123.123.123.123 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Aug 26 13:36:19 123.123.123.123 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [lukas]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you are having is that you haven't set the permission escalation user password. In Ansible, when we need `root` permissions, we set the `become` variable. The method for becoming `root` may vary, so you can set the way using the `ansible_become_method`.

Regarding your problem, I think you need to set up the `ansible_become_user` and `ansible_become_password` before running your `playbook`. You can do it in your inventory, or wherever it feels right for your case.

[Here is the link to the variable list you can configure to modify how Ansible will connect to the hosts.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

You can get more information about privilege escalation on the ["Understanding Privilege Escalation"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#id3) of Ansible Docs.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for input but none of described flags works for me.

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried to configure them?

Answer (score 1):

Just now I had the same issue and my command was

```
./ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -b --become-user root --extra-vars "ansible_become_pass= myPass" --become-method su
```

after removing the space in

```
"ansible_become_pass=[space]myPass" --> "ansible_become_pass=myPass"
```

I tried executing again and got

```
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:[random string].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

And I was like wt fun?

and then I saw that when executing this playbook I already was a `root` user
so I've changed to a different user and tried executing this command again and thank God it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the problem relates to  [PAM](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-pam-in-centos-ubuntu-linux/) **auth** module. In short, I added `auth sufficient pam_permit.so` line to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file. In long this is how I arrived to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657645/pam-unixsudoauth-conversation-failed-auth-could-not-identify-password-for/57673222#57673222).

**Be aware that there can be a million of reasons for PAM to fail, thus this solution might not work for you.**

```sh
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo

#%PAM-1.0
# Fixing "auth could not identify password for [username]" ssh problem.
auth       sufficient   pam_permit.so

# Original config below
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    include      system-auth
```